# Discrete Math Proving two formulas are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hi I have this really tough question which Iv'e been breaking my head on, It would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction. Here is the question:
I need to Prove that the two formulas are equal by using the laws of Logic
   $(p \land q) \vee (\neg p \land r) \vee (q \land r) = (p \land q) \vee (\neg p \land r)$

I need to prove that these two formulas are equivalent ( by using the laws of logic). I've tried doing this:

$(p \land q) \vee r \land (q \vee \neg p) = (p \land q) \vee (\neg p \land r)$

But here I get kinda stuck because I cant change the order. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: if you are allowed, you could also just make a truth table

Comment: I am meant to solve it with a truth table & using the laws of logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land R) \lor (Q \land R) = \text{ (Adjacency)} $$

$$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land R) \lor (P \land Q \land R) \lor (\neg P \land Q \land R) = \text{ (Absorption x 2)} $$

$$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land R)$$

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are explicitly asked to transform one side to the other, why not just write down a table of the values of the left- and right-hand side for all values of p, q and r? This is 8 rows to do.

Also, you may want to use DeMorgan's rule to transform both the left- and right-hand side to their Normalised forms (Conjunctive or Disjunctive) - those will turn out idenrical.

Comment: What do you mean by that? taking the negative out of the brackets?

Comment: I need to transform one side to the other

Comment: I meant this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form. If you can transform both sides to the same thing, then you can transform one side to the other via that same thing.